# The most efficient way to work with list of lists?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

Having a data frame (`df`) in which the components of one of the columns (`df$list`) are lists with different lengths, what is the best way to apply a function on this column and save the results in a new column?

Following is what I have tried, but it is extremely slow for my data frame (10k rows, not too large). I'm looking for alternative better ways to do this task.

```
df$new <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) myFunc(x$list))
```

Example:

```
# constructing df & DF
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("A",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

DF <- data.frame(c = c(1:8), d = c(8:1))
row.names(DF) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")

# list of lists
df_red <- aggregate(list(track = 1:NROW(df)), df[,1:2], '[')
df_red$list_1 <- apply(df_red, 1, FUN = function(x) row.names(DF[(x$track),]))

# Function
searchInDF <- function(list){DF[list,]$d}

# apply function on a list of list
df_red$list_2 <- apply(df_red, 1, FUN = function(x) searchInDF(x$list_1))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Probably best to create/change to a different data structure. List columns are rarely a good idea.

Comment: Please see the update

Answer (score 3):

Here we create such a data frame `DF` and then find the length of each component of column `b`.  This assumes that the sapply returns a simple vector.

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
DF$b <- list(list("a", "b"), list("c", "d", "e"))

DF$c <- sapply(DF$b, length)
```

or if the new column is itself a list:

```
DF$c <- lapply(DF$b, rev)
```

Also try these alternatives:

```
replace(DF, "c", sapply(DF$b, length))
replace(DF, "c", list(lapply(DF$b, rev)))

transform(DF, c = sapply(b, length))
```

(Of course, in the particular case of `length` we could have replaced `sapply(...)` with just `lengths(DF$b)` .)

Comment: In above example should I expect `transform(df_red, c = sapply(list_1, searchInDF))` to work?

Comment: Have revised answer to address the case where the new column is a list.

Comment: Thanks. They all work fine, but as slow as `apply` that I've mentioned in the question. Not sure what causes this. I have to more investigation on the input/output. Or maybe the way I have defined myFunction is causing it...

Comment: Assign the new list to a variable and then assign that variable to the data frame in a separate step so that you can separate out the two from a performance viewpoint.